# BadSqlGrammarException for grant all privileges

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi tenant user authentication system. the data source changes per request via a lookup key.
After creating a tenant database I am trying to grant all the privileges to the admin user.
But jdbc template is throwing BadSQLGrammarException while trying to execute the query.

Below is the code

```
package com.example.authenticationservice.dao_holder;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.authenticationservice.dto.TenantDbInfoDto;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Data
@Repository
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PROTECTED, makeFinal = true)
public class TenantDao  {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public TenantDao(@Qualifier("mainDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public List<TenantDbInfoDto> getTenantDbInfo(DatabaseCreationStatus creationStatus) {
        String query = "select id, db_name, name, db_password " +
                "from tenants " +
                "where creation_status = :creationStatus";
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("creationStatus", creationStatus.getValue());

        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, params, (rs, rowNum) -> {
            TenantDbInfoDto dto = new TenantDbInfoDto();
            dto.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
            dto.setDbName(rs.getString("db_name"));
            dto.setUserName(rs.getString("name"));
            dto.setDbPassword(rs.getString("db_password"));
            return dto;
        });
    }

    public void createTenantDb(String dbName, String userName, String password) {
        String createDbQuery = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + dbName;
        jdbcTemplate.execute(createDbQuery);
        log.info("Created database: " + dbName);
        String query = "grant all privileges on *.* to ':userName'@'localhost' identified by ':password' with grant option";
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        //params.addValue("dbName", dbName);
        params.addValue("userName", userName);
        params.addValue("password",password);
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, params);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>authentication-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>authentication-service</name>
    <description>Soopure authentication service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.76.Final</version>
            <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.76.Final</version>
                <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties :

```
spring.profiles.active=development
server.port=8893
spring.application.name=authentication-service
eureka.client.enabled=false

logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.com.example=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auth
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
 # spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
liquibase.enabled=false
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/migrations/main_db/db.changelog-master.yml
spring.freemarker.suffix=.ftl
spring.freemarker.settings.recognize_standard_file_extensions=false
spring.freemarker.check-template-location=false
sp.authentication.expireInterval=864000
sp.authentication.issuer=authentication-service
sp.authentication.audience=soopure-frontend
sp.authentication.admin_user_id=admin
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

security.ignored=true
security.basic.enabled=false
```

error thrown :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [grant all privileges on *.* to ':userName'@'localhost' identified by ':password' with grant option]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:101)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1580)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:675)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:968)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:989)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:328)
        at com.example.authenticationservice.dao_holder.TenantDao.createTenantDb(TenantDao.java:60)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
        at com.example.authenticationservice.dao_holder.TenantDao$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createTenantDb(<generated>)
        at com.example.authenticationservice.services.TenantServiceImpl.saveTenant(TenantServiceImpl.java:74)
        at com.example.authenticationservice.controllers.TenantController.createTenant(TenantController.java:56)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
```

The syntax seems to be correct of the query but still error is thrown.

Comment: Besides the deprecation of `grant ... identified by` in current MySQL, you also have put parameter placeholders inside quoted strings, which is not valid.